# Display List of Objects in a VF page not working as expected

Tags: apex, visualforce, soap-api, controller, json

To put you on perspective, I've created a Detail Page Button that displays in a new window some result data from a callout to a SOAP web service.

The thing is, I've tried it in a sanbox, and it works perfectly. It displays the data in JSON format (for testing) and then in a display block after deserialize the JSON:

[image]

However, surprisingly for me, I've repeated the process in another Sandbox (adjusting of course the code to the new objects attributes name in the new sandbox) and the result is as follow:
[image]

This is the code for the Apex page:

```
<apex:page controller="AlumnosFromOP_Controller">

<apex:pageBlock title="Listado de alumnos matriculados">
    <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic" value="Información de todos los alumnos matriculados en el Grupo:  {0} ({1}).">
        <apex:param value="{!groupName}"/>
        <apex:param value="{!groupID}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock title="Test">
    <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic" value="{0}">
        <apex:param value="{!testVar}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock title="Students">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!alumnosList}" var="alumno">
        <apex:column value="{!alumno.nombre__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!alumno.Primer_Apellido__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!alumno.email__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!alumno.DNI__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

And the code in the Controller where the callout is made:

```
    public class AlumnosFromOP_Controller
    {    
    public String groupID{get;set;}
    public String groupName{get;set;}
    public String testVar{get;set;}
    public List<Alumno__c> alumnosList{get;set;}

    //Constructor 
    public AlumnosFromOP_Controller(){

        groupID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('gID');
        groupName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('gNombre');

        alumnosList = new List<Alumno__c>();

        String myJSON = getAlumnosFromOP(groupID);

        testVar = myJSON;

        alumnosList = (List<Alumno__c>)JSON.deserialize(myJSON, List<Alumno__c>.class);
    }


    private String getAlumnosFromOP(String groupID)
    {
        try{
                //Open connection with SOAP web service
                OP_SF_Interaction.OP_SF_InteractionPort stub = new  OP_SF_Interaction.OP_SF_InteractionPort();

......
```

So, as in both cases, the JSON is well returned from the callout to the SOAP web service, I'm assumning **¿the bug is in the process of deserializing the JSON?**; is the List alumnosLIst the one is displaying in the  first case but not displaying in the second one

But it's odd, because the JSON deserializing doesn't creates any exception or error.

I'm running out of ideas...

**UPDATE**
A comparison of the debugging in both sandbox, just in case it helps.
[image]

Comment: Just to be sure: which API version did you save the class against? Only after 24.0 the JSON.deserialize returns an error for missing fields on an object.

Comment: @guy I'm using the 33.0 API version

Comment: It must be a mismatch between the 2 object models (e.g. API object/field names). You say you adjusted the code to the new attribute names. But the fieldnames in the JSON strings still look the same. What if you put a system.debug(alumnosList); after the deserialize?

Comment: @guy I've put the System.debug(alumnosList) and it returns  "15:45:35:524 USER_DEBUG [19]|DEBUG|(Alumno__c:{}, Alumno__c:{}, Alumno__c:{}, Alumno__c:{}, Alumno__c:{}, Alumno__c:{}, Alumno__c:{})", it doesn't transform the JSON into objects =( but I've compared the two objects in each sandbox and all fileds have the same attribute names, so the problem isn't about that. I've included an image of the debugging in the question in case it helps.

Comment: Does you system admin profile have viewing rights to those fields? If deployed via deployment sets that is not done by default..

Comment: @guy Oh man, genius! The creation of the objects wasn't done by me, I was assuming that all permissions were granted to me as Admin.  Thanks so much! You can post it as Answer if you want =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does you system admin profile have viewing rights to those fields? If deployed via deployment sets that is not done by default..

Comment: Oh man, genius! I was assuming that all permissions were granted to me as Admin. Thanks so much!